# Detecting bluetooth 'call' button press

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth headset which is able to communicate with my phone. It has one large 'call' button which answers/ends calls.

I am trying to make an app which will be able to intercept when the call button is pressed. I have tried using an intent filter:

```
<receiver android:name=".MediaButtonIntentReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

but the call button does not appear to be classified as a media_button

any ideas on how I can achieve this? I would just like to know when the call button is pressed

Comment: Have you read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10147953/1267661 ?

Comment: Yes, didn't help unfortunately. I can detect 'play' buttons from a wired headset using that code, but not from my bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

try

> android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL_BUTTON

I'm not sure about it.. I think it fires for all call buttons, including any physical call buttons on the phone and buttons on the headsets .etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the button is currently bringing up the Voice Dialer (mine does), you want [ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND). Add the following to your intent filter:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Comment: How would I then use this in my code?  A callback function for example?

Comment: @Adam Google for "android BroadcastReceiver"

Comment: @chrispy see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274868/detecting-bluetooth-headset-call-button-press-in-android)