# detecting bluetooth headset call button press in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing a calling app. So i need to pick/hangup call from bluetooth device too . But i just can not get the key press event from bluetooth headset.
I have tried with Broadcast and audio manager but only getting play/pause, pre and next button callbacks .

```
public class MediaButtonIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent .getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);

            if (event == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intents.ACTION_PLAYER_PAUSE));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

menifest is

```
<receiver android:name=".net.MediaButtonIntentReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I need to get the event only when my activity is alive so i have use onKeyDown and dispatchKeyEvent methods of activity too but nothing seems to work. its giving me same result and previous.
There must be a way cause System phone app is getting this event starting the dialer. Pls Suggest me some useful way to do it .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to listen for `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL` and `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL`

A complete list of KeyEvents can be found here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Keep in mind that call handling for most headsets (wired or not) use the play/pause button too for ending a call.

EDIT:

Try this in your dispatchKeyEvent:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "CALLING!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Keep in mind that you should use `event.getKeyCode();` instead of `event.getAction();` when dealing with the static KEYCODE_{SOMEKEY} integers.

Comment: Thx for the reply seems like a right way to do it after reading the documentation . But I am not getting this event callback in  dispatchKeyEvent . Can you please tell me how to catch these two events

Comment: Not able to get event in dispatchKeyEvent . Have you tried this code ? cause i checked it its not working

Comment: @ADM Yes, I tried this in a new project on the Android emulator using android 7.1. I simulated the call button by using `adb shell input keyevent 5`. 5 in this case is the KeyCode for the call button.

Comment: Yeah but what i need to get event when the call button on bluetooth device is pressed . In case of bluetooth its not working .whereas I am able to get all 3 Media buttons callbacks play,next and pre . But can't get it for call button

Comment: @ADM Have you tried setting break points in your code to see what event type you get in dispatchKeyEvent?. Does dispatchKeyEvent get called at all?

Comment: i debugged it . Its not getting called

Comment: You stated that pressing that button opened the system phone app. I think the system phone app is doing that by using this Intent filter:
``<action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />``

Maybe you can try to use that to call functions in your activity but unless I know what actions are bound to that button I think this is the most I can do to help you.

Comment: @ADM Is it possible that the phone app has a higher priority than your app? take a look at the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287116/android-registering-a-headset-button-click-with-broadcastreceiver

Comment: Tried that too . I am using a hbs 730 device FYI . May be i should check it on some others .

Comment: @ADM That sounds like a good idea. Sadly I can't test this with real bluetooth devices since I don't own any. If you find anything please post it as your own answer so people with the same problem can solve it too.

Comment: Yeah sure . Didn't get anything yet. i'll keep digging. Thx 4 help

Comment: No luck .. I kept looking for solution but didn't find any .

Comment: @ADM found any solution? I have almost identical scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get event **KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK**

```
 if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK) {
  //do somethingenter code here
}
```